# Send json data (asynchronous) to my response

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

So,upon request I respond with a basic template(I use ejs) and I want to add json data to it when I get from an external API.
I have noticed that I can't use res.render or res.write twice(I get errors) so I really don't know what to do.Any ideas?

Comment: The description is to vague to give you specific answer. Also there is no code to work with. If you want an answer update your question.

Comment: It's quite simple really.How can I send a response twice in express.Do I need to do res.send twice?Cause that gives me an error.

Comment: Is that our question? If you can send response twice? That makes no logical sense. If you show some code I can see suggest a solution.

Comment: Best way to ask question here to put code stuff where you are stuck, so that someone can look this.

Answer (score 0):

You can only send one response for each request. So you either need to do two requests or combine the data you want to send into one response.